# CScope indexing with C++ and scoped function parameters

Tags: c++, cscope

I'm using [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) to create an index of some C++ source code. Mostly it works great but it has problems when parsing function names that have parameter types that are scoped (using '::'). For example:

```
void SomeClass::doSomethingAwesome( const std::string& input )
{
}
```

When I use the cscope interface to "Find this C symbol:" I get this:

```
  File              Function      Line
0 doSomethingAwesome <global>  1 void SomeClass::doSomethingAwesome( const std::string& input )
```

The important bit is the global tag. It should be 'doSomethingAwesome'.

For another function without any scoped parameters e.g.

```
void SomeClass::doSomethingElse( int input )
```

I get this:

```
  File              Function      Line
0 doSomethingElse doSomethingElse  1 void SomeClass::doSomethingElse( int input )
```

Note the Function field now matches the function name. I can now successfully search in cscope for other functions that call this function. I could not do that with doSomethingAwesome(). In addition any functions which are only called from doSomethingAwesome() will not show up as having been called by *any* function since doSomethingAwesome() has not been recognised as a function by cscope.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this an issue in cscope's parsing of the function?